# Метод, считывающий данные из потока ввода и возвращающий char[n]

Tags: c++, io

Необходимо прочесть из потока ввода данные ( терминал ), включая пробел, при этом не записывая их сразу.
Допустим я хочу выяснить, строка какого размера была введена.
Вместо создания переменной, почему я не могу сразу узнать размер потока ввода?

```
string data;
getline(cin, data) // плохой метод
cout << data.size();
```

```
cout << readline().size(); // хороший метод, который я ищу
```

Comment: `string readline() {string data;
getline(cin, data); return data;}`

Comment: Поток - вещь, которая работает *по одному символу*. Вы вообще не можете определить для *потока* такое понятие, как размер. И не можете потом вернуться в начало. Например, я ввел строку. Подумал, ввел вторую. Или не ввел. Но поток не закрыт - как вы можете в этот момент выяснить, введу ли я еще строку или нет?... Если даже строка... Поток идет по модему, например. Или com-порту. С пересылками, переподключениями - все байты по одному. Пока все байты не будут приняты - узнать, что строка закончилась - невозможно...